# Is it possible to make search keywords work for a dynamic site?

Tags: search

For example,  I can set up a keyword for https://searchcraigslist.org/
but when I try using it, it just goes to the site and then I manually have to search on the site which defeats the purpose. The same issue happens with custom Google search engines. I've tried it in Chrome but it's the same issue in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

this depends entirely on the site itself, and how it was programmed. some sites offer services using predictable arguments like perhaps a url containing `search/?q=Some%20Search%20Term` but that is entirely up to the web application designer. there is no universal means by which you might perform a search that would work the same (or at all) on all sites.

If the web application in questions puts the relevant parameters you want on it urls, then you can save a bookmark or establish a keyword, but if they don't its not within your power to change how the application does work.